# Am I well connected to UDP Multicast? C#

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

I have this code, but I don't know if I am well connected or joined to the multicast group. I can send and receive messages through the normal IP "ip". But I don't know if I should do anything more to receive messages through multicast. I have this code:

```
    public void UDPConnect()
    {
        socket = new UdpClient(25504); 
        try
        {
            endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 2600);
           
            socket.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(multicastIP));
            socket.Connect(endPoint); 
            
            byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, from the client");
            socket.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

            ConnectToServer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print("Exception thrown " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToServer()
    {
        InitializeClientData();

        isConnected = true;
        StartCoroutine(ClientSend.VisualStartupCor()); 

        socket.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);
    }

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] _data = socket.EndReceive(_result, ref endPoint);
            socket.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);
           
            if (_data.Length < 4)
            {
                Instance.Disconnect();
                return;
            }

            HandleData(_data);
        }
        catch
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

And this is my server code, just too simple. I just wanna to test if I can send and receive for the Client. As you can see, I have put the multicast IP that I use (231.1.1.10) in the Send method. When I send a message from the client, this server answers by sending the same message to the client. My client, in Unity, detects this message. It means that the multicast connection is successful?

```
var udp = require('dgram');

// --------------------creating a udp server --------------------

// creating a udp server
var server = udp.createSocket('udp4');

// emits when any error occurs
server.on('error',function(error){
console.log('Error: ' + error);
server.close();
});

// emits on new datagram msg
server.on('message',function(msg,info){
console.log('Data received from client : ' + msg.toString());
console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, info.address, info.port);

//sending msg

server.send(msg,info.port,'231.1.1.10',function(error){
if(error){
client.close();
}else{
console.log('Data sent !!!');
}

});
});

//emits when socket is ready and listening for datagram msgs
server.on('listening',function(){
var address = server.address();
var port = address.port;
var family = address.family;
var ipaddr = '192.XXX.X.XX';
console.log('Server is listening at port' + port);
console.log('Server ip :' + ipaddr);
console.log('Server is IP4/IP6 : ' + family);
console.log(address);
});

//emits after the socket is closed using socket.close();
server.on('close',function(){
console.log('Socket is closed !');
});

server.bind(2600);
```

Comment: Do you have a _question_? I.e. a _specific_ problem that you need help with? Stack Overflow isn't here to review code or provide design guidance. Please read [mcve] and [ask], for starters, to have a better idea of what kinds of questions are appropriate here and how to present them in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Of course I have a question! I just want to know, as @Xavi has undestood, if I am well connected to the multicast group, with that code. He says that maybe sending a message to the server and forcing it to answer in a multicast way. So I publish here my Server code and explain a bit things, just to know if all that means that I am successfully connected to the multucast group...

Comment: Hi James. You have posted a copy of this question, which indicates that you are not satisfied with the answer you got here. I see that you have given feedback on the existing answer - unsuccessfully I see. Please consider adding details to your question and focusing it on the detail you still/most need help with.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch. Yes, thats true. @Xavier gave me an answer and because of that, I added my server code and ask him again. Because of that, I create a new question with that server code, because it seems Xavier (and anyone more who ask for more details of my question) could understand better my question and try to solve it. I just want to know if that receiving that message from the server (to the multicast adress) into the Client, means that I have successfully connected to the multicast group... Thats all...

Answer (score 1):

UDP doesn't have a connected status, when you call a JoinMulticastGroup the socket sends a IGMP (Internet Group Management Protocol) packet to the service requesting membership to the multicast group.

If the client is accepted to the group, you can start receiving data on the socket

```
socket.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);
```

Basically there is no way to know if the server is going to send you a message, the point of UDP is to not maintain a connection.  You could create a method to ping (send a message) the server and force it to multicast, which sort of looks like what you are trying to do with the "Hello, from the client" message

For more info on multicast groups check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.joinmulticastgroup?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I have put a new comment with my server code. Is my client multicast connection working, then?

Comment: Hi @Xavier, I have put my server code in the question. Is my client multicast connection working, then?

Comment: From the server code if your client receives 'Data Sent!!' then you are connected to the multicast.

Comment: Yes, my Server console app shows 'Data sent! ',  and I receive the message in the Client. Thank you so much, really appreciate your time and answer :)